# Python skip a function if the file already exists

Tags: python, function

I need to create a skip function in python which skips my download code if the file already exists.

How the function should work:
(If the file exists then no need to run this code, just skip to next code.
And if it doesn't exist then run this code and then run the next code)

```
    Filecheck = os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER,"test"+version+"exe")
    print Filecheck

    if not os.path.exists(Filecheck):


     base_url = urlJoin(LINK, + version + "_multi.exe")
     print base_url

     filename2 = "%s_%s_.exe" % (software.capitalize(),version)
     original_filename = os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, filename2)


     if writeFile(original_filename, httpRequestFile(base_url), "wb") and os.path.exists(original_filename):
        print "Download done"
```

Comment: You can probably use the answers to [How do I check if a file exists using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if not os.path.exists(<path-to-file>):
    download_file()
```

---

I'm guessing this is what you mean, though it's very hard to tell.

```
filename = "%s_%s_.exe" % (software.capitalize(),version)
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, filename)):
    base_url = urlJoin(LINK, + version + "_multi.exe")
    writeFile(original_filename, httpRequestFile(base_url), "wb")
```

FYI if you use `requests` you don't need `httpRequestFile`, so you can simplify your code to:

```
import requests
from urllib2 import urljoin
filename = "%s_%s_.exe" % (software.capitalize(),version)
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, filename)):
    with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(requests.get(urljoin(LINK, version + "_multi.exe")).content)
```

Comment: So you mean, it should look like this? see my changes

Comment: @user1823753 I don't understand your code, but I've made a best guess. See above.